# Remove charset from content-type in WSO2 ESB

Tags: character-encoding, wso2, content-type

I was given a RESTful service which I need to invoke with

```
Content-Type: application/xml
```

the problem is that WSO2 ESB automatically adds a charset:

```
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8
```

which is not supported by the service

In WSO2 ESB the service is invoked in the following way:

```
        <header action="set"
                expression="get-property('PhysicalAddress')" name="To"/>
        <property action="set" name="HTTP_METHOD" scope="axis2"
            type="STRING" value="PUT"/>
        <property action="set"
            expression="concat('Basic ', base64Encode(concat(get-property('LOGIN'),':',get-property('PASSWORD'))))"
            name="Authorization" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
        <property action="set" name="messageType" scope="axis2"
            type="STRING" value="application/xml"/>
        <call>
            <endpoint>
                <default format="rest">
                    <timeout>
                        <duration>120000</duration>
                        <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
                    </timeout>
                </default>
            </endpoint>
        </call>
```

How can I remove the charset from Content-Type header?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<property name="setCharacterEncoding" value="false" scope="axis2" />
<property name="setCharacterEncoding" value="false" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
```

Set the property `setCharacterEncoding` to `false`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use below property and change the ContentType header

```
 <property name="ContentType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
```

Comment: This property dose not remove the charset=UTF-8 from Content-Type header